# DB persist from-to value in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I'm currently working on a DB design in SQL Server 2016.

Given is the following table `tProjects`:

```
Column Name | Data Type    | Allow Nulls
--------------------------------------
PID         | int          | no
Title       | varchar(255) | no
Price       | money        | yes
```

So far so good, the problem is the following:

*I need to somehow persist the price range (value range) priceFrom and priceTo.*

Do you know how to create a relation to persist the from - to values in a table in my DB and reference this these range prices in my table tProjects?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: What would be wrong with just adding columns for `priceFrom` and `priceTo`?

Comment: how to get the `priceFrom` and `priceTo` ?

Comment: thanks, yes sounds actually good. Though I was thinking, perhaps there is an alternative solution such as a junction table.. hmm